# How to organize models in a node.js website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, express, sequelize.js

I have just started experimenting with building a website using node.js, and I am encountering an issue when organizing the models of my project.

All the real world examples I have found on the Internet are using Mongoose. This library allows you to define your models in a static way. So you can write this:

```
// models/foo.js
module.exports = require('mongoose').model('Foo', ...);

// app.js
mongoose.connect(...);

// some_controller_1.js
var Foo = require('./models/foo');
Foo.find(...);

// some_controller_2.js
var Foo = require('./models/foo');
Foo.find(...);
```

But since I don't want to use MongoDB, I need another ORM. And all the other ORMs I have found don't allow this. You first need to create an instance, and then only you can register your models. Also they don't seem to allow access to the list of registered models.

So I tried doing this:

```
// models/user.js
var registrations = [];
module.exports = function(sequelize) {
    var result = null;
    registrations.forEach(function(elem) {
        if (elem.db == sequelize)
            result = elem.value;
    });
    if (result) return result;


    // data definition
    var user = sequelize.define("User", ...);


    registrations.push({ db: sequelize, value: user });
    return user;
};
```

Which I can use this like:

```
// some_controller_1.js
var Foo = require('./models/foo')(app.get('database'));
Foo.find(...);  // using Foo
```

But these small header and footer that I have to write on every single model file are a bit annoying and directly violate the "don't repeat youself" principle. Also, while not a huge issue, this is kind of a memory leak since the "sequelize" object will never be freed.

Is there a better way to do, which I didn't think about?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an article about handling models with sequelize here: http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express#the-application

You basically just create a `models/index.js` as described here: http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express#block-3-line-0

Afterwards you just put your model definitions within files in the models folder as pointed out here: http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express#block-4-line-0